# Add addEventListener for blur to lightning:inputField

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript, lightning-experience, javascript-controller

I want to invoke a method when inputfield is off from focus state(blur). I am trying as below but i am not able to get the alert statement when the cursor is out of focus from field . Can some one help me out here

**In Component**

```
<aura:handler name="render" value="{!this}" action="{!c.onRender}"/>
<label for="Subject">Subject</label>
<lightning:inputField fieldName="Subj"  aura:id="Subj" onchange="{!c.search}" value="{!v.sValue}" disabled="{!v.disableSubject}"/>
        `
```

**In Renderer**

```
({ afterRender: function (component, helper) {
        var afterRend = this.superAfterRender();
        helper.addListeners(component)
        return afterRend;
    },
})
```

**In Helper**

```
addListeners : function (component){
  var cmp = component.find("Subj");
  console.log('listners');
  cmp.getElement().addEventListener("blur", function(){
        alert('Method invoked');
      });       
}
```

Comment: its not clear what you are trying to do, blur and 'cursor' hover are two different things, which one are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to blur @glls

Comment: Does the javascript execution ever reach 'addListeners'? Your render-handler calls onRender, but the function you cite is called afterRender...

Comment: @Salesforcedeveloper, any answer you got on this?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? facing similar issue